# SimpleDateFormat formats 2 'same' dates differently

Tags: java, date, csv

Now this one baffles me a lot...

Consider the following 2 dates

```
Fri Dec 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Fri Dec 11 23:59:59 CET 2015
```

When i put both of these dates into SimpleDateFormat i get 2 different results...

```
Date dateFrom = Fri Dec 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Date dateTo = Fri Dec 11 23:59:59 CET 2015

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String formatedFromDate = formatter.format(dateFrom);
String formatedToDate = formatter.format(dateTo);

System.out.println(formatedFromDate); 
System.out.println(formatedToDate);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1st:  11/12/2015
2nd:  11-12-2015
```

Now if someone could shed some light on what is happening here I would really appreciate it.

PS. I tried creating separate formatter for the other date but still same effect.

EDIT:

Ok so below code is part of css export file.

```
// os.getStart() returns = Fri Dec 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
// os.getEnd() returns = Fri Dec 11 23:59:59 CET 2015
// 
// os.getStart() & os.getEnd() looks like

Date start;
Date end;
// SEPARATE PACKAGE
public Date getStart() {
        if(start==null) {
            log.warning("Null start!");
            start=new Date();
        }
        return start;
}
public Date getEnd() {
    if(end==null) {
        log.warning("Null end!");
        end=new Date();
    }
    return end;
}
// setDates are called when date from database is taken - so no rocket science here

// CSV EXPORT FILE
Date dateFrom = os.getStart();
Date dateTo = os.getEnd();

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String formatedFromDate = formatter.format(dateFrom);
String formatedToDate = formatter.format(dateTo);

if(names==null) {
       return;
}
Iterator it;%><%= title %>,<%= messages.getString("calls") %>,<%= messages.getString("answered") %><%= (hasTimes) ? ","+messages.getString("h_time") : "" %>,From Date,To Date<%
it=breakdown.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
        Integer idInt=(Integer)it.next();
        String key=(String)names.get(idInt);
        OrderlyStats.Breakdown value=(OrderlyStats.Breakdown)breakdown.get(idInt);
%>
<%= dateFrom %> //<----Fri Dec 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
<%= dateTo %> //<----Fri Dec 11 23:59:59 CET 2015
<%= ("Queue".equals(type)) ? displayNames.get(key) : key %>,<%= value.calls %>,<%= value.answered %><%= (hasTimes) ? ","+Helper.formatDouble(value.time,1) : "" %>, <%= formatedToDate %>,<%= formatedToDate %><% } %>
```

Comment: there must be a mistake somewhere else, I've just tested your code receiving both times `11/12/2015`

Comment: you write to formatedToDate but print formataedToDate

Comment: @Rustam its just a typo i made when writing to SO.

Comment: Please provide a M**C**VE

Comment: Did you actually build this test ?  How did you actually initialize your dates objects ? Something seems to be missing here. (I'm not getting your result when building my own test from your code)

Comment: @EricMaziade date is just being retrieved from the database and saved into Date object (start/end) thats it

Comment: @MaciejCygan I can't reproduce the issue (I've generated the Date instances from Calendar to get the same dates and time zones you specified).... since the separators are specified in the date format, it should'nt switch based on locale or timezone, so I'm tempted to suspect something else is interfering with your date, formatter or formatted string.

Comment: @EricMaziade hmm very strange, I'll have to dig in deep down to find what is interfering with the date format. Weird

Comment: @MaciejCygan I've double checked and confirm that SimpleDateFormat would *not* adjust the date separators based on locale (using DateFormat.getDateInstance will consider locale, though).   From the code you've posted, I don't really see what could be causing this other than some other part of the process altering the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are expressed in the CET timezone. Is that your default timezone?
You can specify the target timezone in your date formatter:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
```