# Java DateFormat conversion automatically increases hour by 1

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, date-format

I am trying to take date in string and its input format string and converting the date in output format. However after conversion into Date, the java code increases the number of hours by one. I am not able to understand what causes the bug.

My Code:

```
try {
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    Date date = inputFormat.parse(parameterValue);
    parameterValue = outputFormat.format(date);
    return parameterValue;
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    // take action
}
```

format string: `ddMMMyyyy / hh:mm z`

Input Date: `07DEC2015 / 10:02 GMT`

Output Date: `07/12/2015 11:02:00`

Comment: What's your system time zone? Oh, and you almost certainly want `HH` instead of `hh`.

Comment: Check out my answer in this post, it's pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223125/simpledateformat-formats-2-same-dates-differently/34223938#34223938

Comment: This is likely to be a timezone issue. Would I be correct in assuming that you are located in mainland Europe, with a timezone 1 hour ahead of GMT? You could try changing the `outputFormat` to add a `z` at the end, and you will get the timezone that it is being presented as, which might explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: I cannot change the output format. But I added this " outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));" to my code and it works perfectly. Thank you!

hh or HH is the same.

Comment: @Anuja `hh` and `HH` are significantly much different. I suggest reading the doc.

Comment: @Basil I think you didn't understand my comment. Maybe I wrote it in a hurry. hh or HH makes no difference to the fact that there is a 1 hour increase. I meant hh or HH the result is the same.

Comment: @BasilBourque is right,  hh is from 1-12 and HH is from 0-23. However, in both cases it will be an hour more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use timezone, in java 8 you can use LocalDate/LocalTime/LocalDateTime:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTimeInstance = LocalDateTime.parse(dateToBeConverted, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatOfDateToBeConverted));
return localDateTimeInstance.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");


/*
  Also check out ZoneDate, ZoneTime (for timezone)
  Checkout - LocalDate, LocalTime
*/
```